# SQL Server database back up incompatibility due to version difference

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, database-backups, database-restore

I am currently using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (Version: 11.0.2100.60). When I restore backup file from the client database, I get this message:

[image]

When I search google for version 12.00.2269, there is no for such kind of version (maybe I am not found).

Please let me know where can I download for that version and after upgrading, it can still restore the database from the backup file 12.00.2269 to  11.0.2100.60?

**

> Update

**

Here is my SQL server info:

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio    11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)   6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML                           3.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer               9.11.9600.19035
Microsoft .NET Framework                  4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                          6.1.7601
```

Here is my Client's SQL server info :

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio          11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)         6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML                                 3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.9600.18837
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.42000
Operating System                                6.1.7601
```

Only different things is Internet Explorer Version and MSXML version.I have no idea why error message shows the version is higher than us.

Comment: You are restoring a backup from a SQL Server version, on an instance of SQL Server with a lower version. You cannot do that. Version 12.x = SQL Server 2014, version 11.x = SQL Server 2012. See [SQL Server versions](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/).

Comment: You are *down*grading, not *up*grading. Why are you doing this?

Comment: If you google for the version you'll find it immediatelly. The very first result is the list of [SQL Server versions](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/). You are trying to restore a SQL Server *2014* database on SQL Server *2012*. Why are you doing this in the first place? If you want to develop with that database install SQL Server Developer Edition. It's free since SQL Server 2016

Comment: I already check the client's sql server version and Its say sql server 2012 and the version is same with me (11.00.21.00).But when i restore the backup file from client's database backup file,its say like that

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Pls check my update info.

Comment: @John that info doesn't matter. The client may say one thing but the *backup file* proves another. You are still trying to restore to a *lower* version. Install a newer one.

Comment: @John BTW Windows 7 is unsupported too. It reached EOL a couple of years ago which means you can't install any SQL Server edition newer than 2014. At least the Developer Edition is a free download

Answer (score 2):

Sql server doesn't have the backward compatibility feature for database restoring function,

It is not possible to downgrade a database. 11.0.2100.60 is the SQL Server 2012 version. There is absolutely no way you can restore or attach this database to the SQL Server 2014 instance you are trying to restore on (11.0.2100.60  is SQL Server 2012). Your only options are:

1. Upgrade this instance to SQL Server 2014 (12.00.2269)
2. Restore the backup you have on a SQL Server 2012 instance, export all the data and import it on a SQL Server 2014 database.

Sql server version details :- http://sqlserverversions.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: @Parasan , Thanks, I understand version no start with 12 is SQL Server 2014 and My client and I is using same SQL server (SQL Server 2012) and Same Version (11.00.21.00) but different the Microsoft MSXML version. I have no idea why I get this error.